# База данных в C++

Tags: c++, база-данных

Дали курсовую работу, суть заключается в том, чтобы создать программу для бронирования номера в гостинице, нужно реализовать базу данных, чтобы вводимая информация сохранялась, по типу кто забронировал и тд и т.п. В принципе я понимаю, что это можно реализовать с помощью обычного текстового файла, но хотелось бы более профессионально сделать, какие простые базы данных существуют для этого? Желательно ещё с ссылками на ресурсы для изучения

Comment: для ваших нужд хватит любой In-memory базы (например sqlite https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm). Если хотите поковыряться серьезнее, то смотрите в сторону postgre/oracle/mysql

Comment: @goldstar_labs, стоит заметить, что речь идет не о in-memory (обычно под этим подразумевают RAM), а о in-process или embedded DB.

Comment: Мне вот любопытно, что такого полезного в этом вопросе и ответе, что их заплюсовали?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Весь курс здесь, на StackOverflow, пасётся... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html), нет необходимости настройки сервера СУБД и может легко распространятся с программой. [Быстрый старт](https://progtips.ru/bazy-dannyx/sqlite-bystryj-start.html)

Comment: Ну или как более сложный, но вариант - развернуть mysql на какой-нибудь машине(у нас в универе есть спец. сервак, где студенты с мускулом работают). А дальше от этой БД плясать в разные стороны, как например у меня в курсовой работе - нужно собрать данные и обработать их на удалённой машине.